# Volumio on Pi: Webserver for both WebUI and Cover-Art

Tags: audio, web-server

How do I use Volumio's webserver to serve both its WebUI and Album Art?

On a Pi running Volumio, I want to configure MPD clients controlling it to show album cover art for browsing.  (It's a must-have for Wife Acceptance Factor.)  Volumio uses its server for the WebUI.  Some clients will use a .jpg in each album's directory as cover art, but it needs a URL.

The MPD server uses port 6600. MPD clients can use a different port to access images, typically 80.

Is there a way to configure Apache2 to server two separate "sites" on two different ports?  (I expected to see a "sites-enabled" directory at /etc/apache2, but nope.)

Answer (score 1):

Workaround without touching Apache2:

Open up directory permissions and Symlink the mnt location into Volumio's website folder:

1. Access a terminal and:

   > chmod -R 777 /var/www/ && ln -s /var/lib/mpd/music /var/www/music
2. In MPoD Connection Settings:

   > - URL http://*Your.pi.ip*:80/music
   > - Filename: Case sensitive.

(Tested this with a local mount (usb) and network share (nas).)

Reference and Thanks:
[Mpod/Mpad cover art and Volumio.](http://www.katoemba.net/makesnosenseatall/forums/topic/mpodmpad-cover-art-and-volumio/#post-25162)

Comment: Update: This works with Volumio 1.55, but not the current release.  Current release is a Volumio 2 Beta that uses a different web server with different configurations.